# How do I call a prototype function from another function?

Tags: javascript

I Have a function called auto with the prototype called create, how do I call the prototype?

```
function auto(){

}
auto.prototype.Create = function(container){
}
```

when I do `auto.call(this);` it just calls the auto function and stops at the end of that function, how do I call the prototype too?

I am calling these from one script to another.

Comment: `this.Create(container)` inside the `auto` function (providing you called it with `new`).

Comment: so are you saying I just need to do is:

Comment: new auto.this.Create(container);

Comment: Or auto = new auto.Create(container);

Comment: `function auto() { this.Create(container); }`, then `var a = new auto()`

Comment: Wherever "`container`" comes from or what that's supposed to be I have no idea.

Comment: I'm trying to call these from another script when I press a button, it then needs to call the auto script which starts with auto as being the main function, will this work? because I have to do auto.call(this) just to access the auto script

Comment: basically it goes: this.button.onDown = window.bind(this); //when it gets to the window function it then does: auto.call(this); //which like I explained before only goes through the main auto function in the next script and stops before the auto. prototype function

Comment: Prototype functions aren't automagically invoked when their "host" function gets invoked. That's not how that works.

Comment: Thank you I have done it now I just did var AUTO = new auto();                    auto.Create(this.container);

Answer (score 0):

First Create a constructor function called 'auto', then write your create function as a prototype method of auto constructor. In order to call methods in prototype you have to create instance of auto function with 'new' keyword.

```
function auto(name) {
  this.name = name;
} 
auto.prototype.create = function (){
  console.log('Creating : ' + this.name);
}
var autoInstance = new auto('Mercedes');
autoInstance.create();
```

Comment: I'm trying to call these from another script when I press a button, it then needs to call the auto script  which starts with auto as being the main function, will this work? because I have to do auto.call(this) just to access the auto script

Comment: basically it goes: this.button.onDown = window.bind(this); //when it gets to the window function it then does: auto.call(this); //which like I explained before only goes through the main auto function in the next script and stops before the auto. prototype function